# Efficient conversion of a 3D numpy array to a 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array in this form:

```
>>>img.shape
(4504932, 2, 2)

>>> img
array([[[15114, 15306],
    [15305, 15304]],

   [[15305, 15306],
    [15303, 15304]],

   [[15305, 15306],
    [15303, 15304]],

   ..., 

   [[15305, 15302],
    [15305, 15302]]], dtype=uint16)
```

Which I want to convert to a 1D numpy array where each entry is the sum of each 2x2 submatrix in the above img numpy array.

I have been able to accomplish this using:

```
img_new = np.array([i.sum() for i in img])
>>> img_new
array([61029, 61218, 61218, ..., 61214, 61214, 61214], dtype=uint64)
```

Which is exactly what I want. But this is too slow (takes about 10 seconds). Is there a faster method I could use? I included above `img.shape` so you had an idea of the size of this numpy array.

EDIT - ADDITIONAL INFO:
My `img` array could also be a 3D array in the form of 4x4, 5x5, 7x7.. etc submatrices. This is specified by the variables `sub_rows` and `sub_cols`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
img.sum(axis=(1, 2))
```

`sum` allows you to specify an axis or axes along which to sum, rather than just summing the whole array. This allows NumPy to loop over the array in C and perform just a few machine instructions per sum, rather than having to go through the Python bytecode evaluation loop and create a ton of wrapper objects to stick in a list.

Comment: That was super fast. Thanks! I am adding now an additional piece of info in my question. Could you comment to let me know if this would still apply.

Comment: @user3250673: `img.sum(axis=(1, 2))` still works. It has no dependence on the size of any axes.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Just realized that I have a small issue. My `img` array is of `dtype=uint16 so I cnanot use directly `img.sum(axis=(1,2))`. Would using astype set to `int32` be a bad idea?

Comment: @user3250673: There's nothing stopping you from using `sum` on an array of dtype uint16, but if you're worried about it overflowing, `sum` has a `dtype` parameter. This sets the dtype of the accumulator used and of the resulting array. However, note that when the dtype of an array has size less than the default platform integer, NumPy will already autopromote the sum to the default platform integer size, so you may already be getting a `uint32` or `uint64` instead of a `uint16`.

Comment: That's what I originally thought as well. But when I run the `img = img.sum(axis=(1,2))` , I get `*** TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: @user3250673: Oh, that's a completely unrelated problem. You're on an old version of NumPy, which doesn't support a tuple `axis`. I recommend updating, but if you can't, you'll have to compute the sum one axis at a time: `img = img.sum(axis=2).sum(axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a numpy method (`apply_over_axes`) is usually quicker and indeed that is the case here. I just tested on a 4000x2x2 array:

```
img = np.random.rand(4000,2,2)
timeit(np.apply_along_axis(np.sum, img, [1,2]))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 721 us per loop
timeit(np.array([i.sum() for i in img]))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 17.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Quicker than using img.sum(axis=(..,..))?

Comment: Nope:( And slower to the answer too. `timeit(img.sum(axis=(1,2)))
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 51.8 us per loop`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
img_new = np.einsum('ijk->i',img)
```

**Verify results**

```
In [42]: np.array_equal(np.array([i.sum() for i in img]),np.einsum('ijk->i',img))
Out[42]: True
```

**Runtime tests**

```
In [34]: img = np.random.randint(0,10000,(10000,2,2)).astype('uint16')

In [35]: %timeit np.array([i.sum() for i in img]) # Original approach
10 loops, best of 3: 92.4 ms per loop

In [36]: %timeit img.sum(axis=(1, 2)) # From other solution
1000 loops, best of 3: 297 µs per loop

In [37]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk->i',img)
10000 loops, best of 3: 102 µs per loop
```